# How to group with Emmet

Tags: emmet

`div>header>ul>li*2>a+footer>p` is not working for me. I need to group whatever is between the `ul` and `a`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group things with Emmet with the brackets. 
In your case: `div>header>(ul>li*2>a)+footer>p` 
Give it a try.

Comment: And by the way here is a good cheat sheet for Emmet: http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/

Comment: Oh, this is really cool, thank you! I'm new with SO and also new with emmet...Your answer is working for me, btw.

Comment: Is it also possible to chat on SO if i have any questions?
eg. Can you and i chat on SO?

Comment: Absolutely, it becomes possible when we continue writing each other with comments. But I believe you won't be able to chat untill you have a specific amount of points. It's best if you check this out in the Help center of SO.